# Change Icon of Swipe to delete button on Tlistview FMX

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I'm using a `TlistView` set to `DynamicAppearence`, and `CanSwipeDelete` is set to `True`.
I somehow can't find a way to set the icon of the delete button to a specific icon I see the property for `DeleteButtonText` but I'm looking to put an icon there instead of text.

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are no icon in the DeleteButton, I think one way to have one is modifying the ListViewStyle, but not an easy one.

First create a create a new stylebook, right click on ListView/ "modify personal style"
[image: First Step]

Select DeleteButton Object
[image: Second Step]

As you see it's a TStyleObject (depend of style sheet you use I think)

So you can see that this object is a region of an image.

[image: BitMapLinks Editor]

Now it's theory using Bitmap Style Designer:

- find the vsf file
- edit image file  or add an image file

you can get images to edit them
[image: Hereyou can get images]

- create the new style

Load this style and change the zone

Comment: I think there is also a "coding way", in a french blog I describe how to use a style  for a puzzle game https://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/138527-sergiomaster/b10132/utilisation-ludique-style-fmx-jeu-taquin/. So I think it's possible to update only the image region by code